# Frequency and appropriateness of contacting employer post application submission

Tags: applications, follow-up

I have submitted an application for an an operations analytics position on a company's own website. They use a third party software enabling the applicant to track their process throughout the hiring / review process. Nothing changed for about a week and half after I submitted my application. The status was they had received my resume and cover letter and were in the process of reviewing them. I decided to write them a message using this software to reiterate my interest and strong qualifications for the position.

Now does writing back after a week and half seem appropriate? On one hand, I want to maintain my interest in the position and demonstrate why I am a solid candidate, however I also don't to seem annoying or desperate, as to make a negative impression on the manager's mind. I would like to hear some insight from someone more experienced.

Appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I find it depends on the company. Some situations, if they don't contact you immediately in 24-48 hours then they have no interest in you. In other cases, I found that when you do contact them, they see that you are interested, and ask you for an interview right then.

I guess what I'm saying is you won't know unless you contact them.

Comment: This does not answer my question at all. I am asking for the appropriateness of asking. I already did ask as per the image